# jQuery - How to prevent the same event handlers to get initialized when an ajax page load occurs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I built a table with jQuery and PHP from scrap. It has real-time searching, table column sorting and pagination (jQuery event handlers check for any change, and then they reload the table with ajax. The table is in a div within a PHP, so it loads the table to the table's div). When any change happens and a ajax loading is fired, the event handlers reload too, because the PHP file changes, having elements in the page which haven't got an event handler before. The problem with it is that this way there will be too many event handlers for the same event.

Here are some simplidied snippets from the jQuery code.

```
// for the first initialization
$('document').ready(function(){
    var tableSettings = setSettings(1, 2, 3); // returns a simple array
    loadTable(tableSettings);
});

// loads the table and the event handlers
function loadTable(tableSettings){
    $('#table_content').load('modules/donations_table.php', tableSettings, function(){
        search();
    });
}

// search() has event handlers like this
$('#location').change(function(){
    var tableSettingsNew = setSettings(1, 2, 4);
    loadTable(tableSettingsNew);  // this is where the problem occurs
});
```

As you can see when a change happens at #location, it changes the tableSettingsNew array and that will be sent with a POST request to donations_table.php to generate the new table rows from the database. After 4 changes at #location, loadTable() function is being called 15 times.

I **know** that I could solve this problem with inline scripts in donations_table.php, but I am searching for a more elegant solution. Is there any way to reset my event handlers, so when the page loads it would destruct then reconstruct them without reloading the whole page?

Comment: 1) detach all event handlers that would be affected by the reload, and re-attach them after
2) using the selector from `.on()`, bind to the parent of all these, and specify the selector, that way new items appended to the parent will automatically come with the event handlers.

Comment: Event delegation is usually the easiest solution. Or don't use `load()`, but instead use `$.ajax`, then turn the HTML response into DOM elements and bind directly to that set of elements.

Comment: You're going way beyond inventing the wheel. http://www.datatables.net/ is a jquery plugin that does everything you're looking for without the need for ajax and page/element reloading.

Comment: @the_pete My first attempt of creating my table was with datatables, but sadly it took me much more time to customize it than to write my own, but thank you.

Comment: @cookiemonster thank you, but fiddling with DOM elements would take more time to code in this almost-ready stage

Comment: @serakfalcon thank you, I will stick with your solution (but I still have to decide which one :) ) 

Thank you all again for the fast and helpful responses.

Comment: @nandoo That's honestly really surprising to hear as, aside from the jquery include and specific block of jquery they give you to add to the top, all you actually need to do is add a `<thead></thead>` block and a `<tr>` full of your column headers wrapped in `<th></th>`.

Comment: @the_pete Yes, I managed to get that far, but I had problems with ranged search with specific date formats, adding a column containing only a checkbox, etc. I don't like plugins, they add a new "layer" to the code witch makes it harder to read. I like to complete a complex task only with my code, because I learn much of it. This post is a great example - I have learnt a lot from this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments **serakfalcon** and **cookie monster** both gave me the right answer: event delegation. [Here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is a short article about it.

In my example, the solution was changing `$('#location').change(function() {...} )` to `$('#table_content').on('change', '#location', function(){})`, because the ajax loaded elements are in #table_content, so this event handler will check everything what happens inside it, so I don't need to load my event handlers, but one time.

Thank you everyone for commenting.